# Changing constructor in a custom VS 2013 template

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on creating a VS2013 C# project template for our "standard operations" jobs.  These are discrete executables executed by a third-party scheduler.  They have common functions within that framework that I'm building into separate libraries (a common engine for the scheduler, a logging component, and a command-line parser).  Each project will have two class files by default: the program executor (program.cs) and the processor, which will contain the business logic.  Other classes can be created by the developer as needed.  I want the processor to be independent of the executor to make it more portable (maybe moving to a new scheduler that operates on libraries versus executables, converting the project to a form, etc.)

The executor creates the references to the engine and logger, so it can use the functionality of those object directly, and also passes them into the processor.

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
Logger log = new Logger(engine.ProcessPath, engine.AppName);

Processor proc = new Processor(engine, log);
```

The default constructor takes those references and assigns them to local members:

```
private Logger log;
private Engine engine;

public Processor(Engine inEngine, Logger inLog)
{
    log = inLog;
    engine = inEngine;
}
```

What I would like to do is template the naming of the processor class.  I know I can do that by using the default place holders for the class and editing the vstemplate, so

```
class $safeprojectname$Processor
```

Results in a class name of the project name with 'Processor' appended, but I can't find a way to rename the constructor to match.  The whole point of this is to again provided portability of the business layer, so the classes can be moved around with out losing the context of the business process.

So, here is the question: is there a way to change the constructor name in a template project?

Also, at the back of my mind is a tickle suggesting there is a better way to go about this whole thing, but I can't place my finger on it.  I'm open to alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach to rename the constructor, e.g.

```
public $safeprojectname$Processor(Engine inEngine, Logger inLog)
{
    log = inLog;
    engine = inEngine;
}
```